# Oracle SQL to delete table entries using having clause

Tags: sql, oracle, having

I have a SQL query which finds userids in a table based on last login date

```
select USER_ID, max(login_time) maxd from MyTable group by User_Id having max(login_time) < (sysdate - 90)
```

I need to delete the entries that this query finds

I have tried

```
DELETE a
FROM   MyTable a
JOIN
(
    select USER_ID, max(login_time) maxd from MyTable group by User_Id having max(login_time) < (sysdate - 90)
) b ON a.USER_ID = b.USER_ID
```

but this results in
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Oracle doesn't support that DELETE JOIN (non-ANSI SQL syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle supports delete join syntax, but it is a bit different than other databases.

```sql
DELETE FROM (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM MyTable a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT USER_ID
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY User_Id
        HAVING MAX(login_time) < (sysdate - 90)
    ) b ON a.USER_ID = b.USER_ID
);
```

Comment: This solution was successful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use your `select` as a subquery:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
  WHERE (user_id, login_time) IN
           -- this is your query:
           (  SELECT USER_ID, MAX (login_time) maxd
                FROM MyTable
            GROUP BY User_Id
              HAVING MAX (login_time) < (SYSDATE - 90));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can correlate on the `ROWID` pseudo-column and use an analytic function:

```sql
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT login_time,
           MAX(login_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS max_login_time
    FROM   mytable
  )
  WHERE  max_login_time < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '90' DAY
  AND    login_time = max_login_time
)
```